# Can the unity networkmanager actually load scenes from streaming assets like loading a build-in scene?

Tags: unity

Can the build in networkmanager load a scene from the streaming assets folder and force all clients to do the same or do i have to load it manually on each client using some remote procedure? I cant find anything about that in the docs or on youtube.

Comment: Did you try it? What were the results?

Comment: No, right now i just got it working by loading the scene using rpc on all local players and set the players to dontdestroyonload. I think maybe the title of my question is bad again, i am looking for something like NetworkServer.singleton.LoadScene(Scene s)